# How to refresh the contents of Jasper Report tables every 5 minutes

Tags: jasper-reports, refresh, jasperserver

I am making a report containing a table using Jasper Report.
I want that table to refresh its content on a specified interval, say every 5 minutes. How to do this?

I am thinking about making a thread to reload the .jasper file.
What do you think? Any body has the same experience?

Answer (score 1):

In iReporter I had this issue. I can get it to refresh by running by doing a preview after every edit.

Answer (score 1):

Go to ***ViewReport.jsp*** on jasper server installation files.

Then add below code for it.(Actually we use java script to do this.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var url = window.location.href; //take current tab url
 var dash = 'http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&_flo...';

 if(url == dash ){
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.reload(1);
    }, 5000);
 }
</script>
```

**url** is the current display report url.

**dash** is the url that we want to refresh. otherwise all the reports will be refresh within every 5 seconds.

**5000** is time gap want to refresh (in milliseconds).

restart the jasper server.

You can add the report link that contains the table you want to refresh data for **url** and **dash** and set the time in milliseconds as you want to refresh it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20549620)

Comment: I removed the link